# Android 10 fullscreen intent launched after turning the device off during heads-up notification

Tags: android, heads-up-notifications

We use heads up notification together with fullscreen intent to show important update to end user when he receives push message from server. This immersive behavior is intentional.

The activity triggered by the fullscreen intent also turns the device ON and gets displayed over the lockscreen.
The application behavior is correct in almost all scenarios:

> - When device is locked and screen is off the intent launches the activity and turns the screen on. User immediately sees our activity.
> - When device is unlocked and user is working with the device, heads up notification is displayed and by clicking on it we start our activity.

But when the device is on, user gets the heads up notification and decides to turn the screen off, the fullscreen intent is immediately triggered too, turning the screen back on and showing our activity. Which is not a desired behavior. I would expect the device to just turn the screen off and let the notification fall back among other notifications.

We can't figure out how to prevent the fullscreen intent to be triggered when user decides to ignore the heads up notification and turn the screen off. Any suggestions or experience?

Comment: Totally unrelated to your problem, but how did you manage to show the full screen intent activity on lock screen. In my case, the notification is shown on the status bar but the activity does not show over lock screen.

Comment: @Dibzmania we use `NotificationCompat.Builder` to create the notification and we use it's method `setFullscreenIntent(...)` to force fullscreen activity instead of notification.

Answer (score 2):

After some testing it turned out this behavior is intended and all applications that are using heads-up notifications with fullscreen intent are behaving the same.
Tested on Phone and Messenger app.